# Change fielderror color?

Tags: java, jsp, validation, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using struts2 validation using the `validate()` method in my Action class. 
I add FieldErrors using `addFieldError()` method. The field error gets displayed on top of each field of my form.

**Action class:
(This validates setMapServerDetails action)**

```
/*---------------------VALIDATION------------------------------------*/
public void validateSetMapServerDetails(){

    if(getMapServer().getServerName().length() == 0){
        addFieldError("mapServer.serverName", "Name is Required");
    }
}
```

The problem is the error gets displayed in plain text, I want the error in red color.

How should I change it to red?

**EDIT:** 
JSP:

```
<title>Configure Map Server</title>

<s:head /> 
</head>
<body>

<s:form action="setMapServerDetails" validate="true">
    <s:textfield name="mapServer.serverName" label="Server Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="mapServer.serverIp" label="Server IP"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="mapServer.serverPort" label="Server Port"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="mapServer.applicationName" label="Application Name"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="mapServer.remarks" label="Remarks"></s:textfield>
    <s:submit value="Save"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

Comment: That would be a CSS issue.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: These fielderrors struts2 adds itself. Where is the CSS for it?

Comment: I don't actually know. If you are using custom tags, is it possible the tags add a `style` attribute to the element? I'd look into source or find out where the actual CSS is.

Comment: Can you post the html tag where the error is displayed after it is rendered? go to `view source`

Comment: It works now giving fielderror in RED. I just added <s:head/> before my </head> closing tag. Anyone has an idea how this worked?

Comment: use simple theme for `<s:actionerror>` and can use `cssErrorClass`, style for this. for details see http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/actionerror.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Struts2 adds `errorMessage` CSS class to error messages. You just need to add this to your CSS:

```
.errorMessage {
  color: red;
}
```

When you put `<s:head>` tag it added default styles to your page where `errorMessage` declaration looks like that:

```
.errorMessage {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha: It is by default.

Answer (score 2):

In Struts2 `addFieldError()` method adds a `<s:fielderror>` tag to the view, and the default css class name of the tag is `errorMessage`.

```
.errorMessage {
    background-color:#FFCCCC;
    border:1px solid #CC0000;
    width:400px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
```

If you want more flexibility (i.e. use your own css class) you can use

```
<s:fielderror cssClass="yourownCSS">
  <s:param>mapServer.serverName</s:param>
</s:fielderror>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div></div>` and give `style` attribute

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
  <div style="color: green;">
     <s:actionmessage/>
  </div>
</s:if>
<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
  <div style="color: red;">
     <s:actionerror/>
  </div>
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ranuka gave good and which will work.

Sometimes it is better to know why we have to give css to `.erroMessage`.

When ever you are using struts validations and if there is a validation error or conversion error struts will generate error message and keep that error message by default in tag.
That  tag name is
`<span class="errorMessage">Your Error message here</span>` tag.

So in the above tag it is very clear that span tag class is `errorMessage`, now you can apply css code to this class `errorMessage`.

That's why in you css we are using

```
.errorMessage {
  color: red;
}
```

Here `.errorMessage` is indicating you are applying css for all tags with `class="errorMessage"` which are nothing but the error message tags.

The above explanation will help you to understand why you have to apply css to `.errorMessage`